# stop program from terminal if running for more than x seconds

Tags: bash, command-line, job-control

so by typing

```
/.blabla
```

I launch the program blabla. Is there a way, from the terminal, to stop (i.e. equivalent of ctrl+c) blabla has been running for more than x secs?
(I'm trying to test a program of which I have not the source on various random inputs, and the thing gets stuck occasionally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use timeout from coreutils package in the repositories:

Installation: `sudo apt-get install coreutils`

Usage: `timeout [-signal] time command`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post detailing several ways to do that : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shell-scripting-run-command-under-alarmclock/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sleep` to accomplish this:

```
./blabla &
pid=$!
(sleep TIMEOUT; kill $pid 2>/dev/null) &
sleeppid=$!
wait $pid
kill -HUP $sleeppid 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works too, but DoR's link is super elegant....

Comment: Yes, it's much easier to do with Perl or Python. :)

Comment: oh, i meant at the end. There's a C program 'doalarm'.